# How many elements in this array [,,]?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript,

can someone explain to me why

[,,] has 2 undefines elements and not three
[1,1,1] - has 3 elements so why [,,] has only two!

Comment: Because you can add an extra `,` after the last element which is ignored instead of raising a syntax error

Comment: that's likely [1, 1, ] has 2 elements

Comment: Last comma is a trailing comma and it's optional.

Comment: See [the detailed documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas) explanations

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is from the definition in ES6, If you do not write anything after the last comma, then the item doesn't count for length.